# Getting error while multipling 2 values from mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to get the `totalamount` of products in the cart

router page:

```
router.get('/place-order', verifyLogin, async (req, res) => {
  let total = await userHelpers.getTotalAmount(req.session.user._id)
  res.render('user/place-order', { total})
})
```

Function for getting `totalamount`:

```
getTotalAmount: (userId) => {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let total = await db.get().collection(collection.CART_COLLECTION).aggregate([
            {
                $match: { user: objectId(userId) }
            },
            {
                $unwind: '$products'
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    item: '$products.item',
                    quantity: '$products.quantity'
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION,
                    localField: 'item',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'product'

                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    item: 1, quantity: 1, product: { $arrayElemAt: ['$product', 0] }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    total: { $sum: { $multiply: ['$quantity', '$product.Price'] } }
                }
            }

        ]).toArray()
        
        console.log(total[0].total);
        resolve(total[0].total)

    })

}
```

ERROR

```
(node:10524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: $multiply only supports numeric types, not string
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bimal Boby\Desktop\E-commerce-Website\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:451:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at processMessage (C:\Users\Bimal Boby\Desktop\E-commerce-Website\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:451:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bimal Boby\Desktop\E-commerce-Website\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:620:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
(node:10524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10524) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: As the error says either or both of the quantity and price has a string value. It would be better to debug if you post the model and data.

Comment: Are both your fields numeric type?

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. Quantity or/and Price is string.

Use `$toInt` to convert it into number and then multiply them .

`{quantity : {$toInt : $quantity}}`
`{Price : {$toInt : $product.Price}}`

Comment: But when i used  $toInt it is giving 0 as a  output.But the product and quantity contain numbers .Now the console is not giving error          console  output [ { _id: null, total: 0 } ]